# Only a single application is apparently able to use i915 driver

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, i915

For some reason, whenever I run any graphic application, everything but the application I just opened freezes.

Sometimes it's inverse: whenever I run any graphic application it opens frozen.

At first I thought it was linux-rt but after booting in the normal kernel the situation didn't change.

Didn't use to happen when I was using Ubuntu.

```
uname -a: `Linux linux 4.1.10-rt10-1-rt #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Thu Oct 29 18:52:22 GMT+5 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

pacman -Q mesa: `mesa 11.0.4-1`

pacman -Q xf86-video-intel: `xf86-video-intel 1:2.99.917+478+gdf72bc5-2`
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have anything in kern.log or dmesg output relating to i915? Also check the Xorg logs for any errors/warnings.

Comment: "DRI2SwapComplete: bad drawable"? `dmesg`: http://pastebin.com/aCXLm7mS `Xorg.0.log`: http://pastebin.com/R5zXvGni

Comment: And `glxinfo`: http://pastebin.com/DC7hgM0y

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding `Option "DRI" "3"` to section Device in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf.